# How to guard my domain from mimic domains which link to my website?

Tags: negative-seo

My main query for SERP search suddenly dropped to the 4th Google page from the 1st page. I looked at my webmaster tools (backlinks), checked all backlinks and found 2 mimic domains that link to my domain. So, all that I did is submitted disavow file with these domains. I also found a whole network of spam pages that link to me.

How to guard our websites against these kinds of mimic domains and toxic backlinks from these websites?

I assume that it is the work of my competitors, but that fact is not helpful to me.

Comment: Your "first mimic" doesn't appear to be a mimic at all to me.  It lists information about your site, including what the meta tags are, but it doesn't copy the whole site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They send backlink to mine domain,what should i do else.I submitted disavov.txt .Anything else buddy?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that that first non-mimic has anything at all to do with your ranking drop.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I cant show you here whole network of bad pages which points to my website,at least from 10 low spam quality pages like this one -> https://laokfkk.cdobson.com/ and this one -> https://rbxsy.gron4.com/ .At least 10.

Comment: @the problem with low quality and spam pages is unrelated to mimicing your website.  (Mimicing means copying - so a site that looks like your site to fool visitors).   For bad backlinks you are doing the right thing by keeping an eye on them and disavowing bad links.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for response.Take a look at mimic domain -> hvalasestro.in.rs.atlaq.com which made backlink to mine domain -> https://hvalasestro.in.rs/ ,so ,i cant see any other weapon to use against that black seo tactic agains my website except disavov tool,but that also isnt happy solution,google must recrawl all of this spam pages and we all know than google crawler visit some pages really rare(one time in 6 months),but i havent other weapon unfortunately.In short,spammers won.

Comment: This is not mimicing or blackl.  hvalasestro.in.rs.atlaq.com picks up generic information about your site and makes the meta information available.  This is in no way black hat - If it supercedes yours, this is a reflection of how poorly you have desinged/ranked your site.  I'm an inaccurate judge as its in a foreign language, but to be blunt your site links to dodgy low quality - as in illegal - content and appears to try and just make money by volumes of low quality content and lots of low quality adverts.  Google wants credible, high quality content and rightly does not like your site.

Comment: You have likely been caught up in Googles new algorithms which are ruthelessly cutting back what they index.

Comment: @davidgo Buddy take a look at mine main page which with  i have rank issue and tell me what is low quality and spam in my website desighn main page -> https://hvalasestro.in.rs/ .This is the only page with ranking issues.Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke - I did. My comments about low quality were of that website.  I'm working off a Google translated version, but even taking that into account your site is very spammy.  Your home page is not great,but not _that bad.  It is, however all-over the place in terms of how Google might try and classify it - Web Creation? Advertisomg agency? Travel Agent?  Stolen Media Broadcaster? Sports Related?  All these are implied by looking at your main website....

Comment: It does not appear very Expert (Second E) in E-E-A-T, nor Authorative, Nor Trustworthy.  Why would Google rank it?

Comment: @davidgo And one more comment,does it natural for you to  made for example domain facebook.atlab.com and write there their meta descriptions and backlink to facebook.com,it doesnt natural for me.If you are sure in your answer put your  answer bellow on voting.Thank you.

Comment: I dont understand what you have written above - or where facebook comes into it.  Having (subdomain.reference).my.platform.domain is not black hat unless im pretendong to be subdomain.reference (as opposed to providing services related to subdomaim.reference).  There are legitimate uses of this naming [although I dont like it].

Comment: Then,why chrome doesnt acept this kind of domains and warn us on "atackers",try it in chrome -> hvalasestro.in.rs.atlaq.com . @davidgo

Comment: @davidgo By the way all of my pages are highly ranked except that main page,average is 4.8 of 70 pages.

Comment: I don't have Chrome, but I do have Chromium, and that site comes up fine for me.  (Also in chrome).

Comment: @davidgo Dude I owe you an apology, Panda probably caught me because I almost added pages for other cities which turned out to be a terrible idea.